# What's up with SVN putting "<<<<<<< .mine" all over the place?

Tags: svn

What's going on here?  I have used TFS and SourceGear Vault and neither of these source code managers corrupt files like SVN.  They actually open up a nice little window giving you the chance to resolve conflicts and then apply the resolved code to your file.  SVN's approach appears to be to litter your code files with "markings" that you have to manually delete after you realize your code doesn't build due to design-time errors or pages don't load because of malformed markup.  The most annoying is when the project file's XML gets corrupted, causing you to have to unload the project and edit the XML manually.

Can someone please tell me that there is a way to tell SVN not to do this so that it behaves like a rational source code manager?

Comment: I recommend Eclipse w/ Subclipse to do your merges and updates. You can do "proactive merges" by viewing conflicts before they update your working copy. You can also see Conflict Warnings in the problem list if your update pulls in conflicts, and resolve them with a nice GUI. It also has the benefit of being platform-neutral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a merge tool or use GUI client like TortoiseSVN which will do the job for you and you will have a similar or better experience with SVN and resolving conflicts.

Comment: Seconded! We use [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) to do this. Makes merges much easier.

Answer (score 5):

You have a conflict.  Not to worry, there's a number of ways to resolve it:

[Here's a handy tutorial on how to solve it from the command line (Windows + Mac)](http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=178)

[This is a list of Mac subversion clients that should resolve conflicts easily](http://suburbia.org.uk/blog/2009/04/08/182507.html)

[On windows, pretty much everyone I know uses TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Also, it's just good form to ask the other people working on the project who committed last and agree on how to resolve the conflicts intelligently.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend using TortoiseSVN and configuring it to use a GUI diff/merge tool.

> It doesn't take too much setting up to use with TortoiseSVN.  Open the Settings dialog from the TortoiseSVN Settings menu.
>   In the External Programs section select Diff Viewer and select the External radio and supply the command line argument:
>
> ```
> path\DiffMerge.exe /t1=Mine /t2=Original %mine %base
> ```
>
> Make sure you supply a valid path to the installed DiffMerge product! When displaying changes this will display your version changes in the left panel with base in the right.
>
> To get the three panel merge select the Merge Tool in the External Programs section, and as before select the External radio and supply the following command line argument:
>
> ```
> path\DiffMerge.exe /t1=Mine /t2=Base /t3=Theirs /r=%merged %mine %base %theirs
> ```
>
> This will display three columns with your version, followed by the base version followed by the repository version - allowing you to merge changes from both sides into the centre at your leisure...

[Source](http://www.manik-software.co.uk/blog/post/TortoiseSVN-and-DiffMerge.aspx)